# how to tell compiler that property MUST be initialized

Tags: c#, initialization, c#-9.0, non-nullable

I have a class like e.g. this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; init; }
    public IImmutableSet<int> Baz { get; init; }
}
```

When I write it that way, I get a compiler warning

> Non-nullable property 'Bar' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable. csharp(CS8618)

There is much content addressing this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67505347/5333340)), but as far as I can see, it is just about how to get rid of the message by either setting a default value or by switching off compiler warnings using a "fake-default" like `null!`.

But in my case, a default value does not make sense.
Instead, I'd like to tell the compiler that these properties must be set explicitly, so that it complains if any of them was NOT set prior to using the object. Just like this is the case with unassigned local variables:

[image]

**Is that possible, and if yes, how?**

I know I could just define a single constructor with arguments, so that using that constructor is the only way to create a new instance. But since I have lots of classes like the above, I would need to write quite of lot of extra code (i.e. the constructors). It'd also be clearer for readers of my code if there was a kind of "must-be-initialized" flag.

Comment: If you override the compiler warning by setting the value to `null!`, you disable the warning explicitly. How should the compiler know that you didn't intend to do that?

Comment: *"tell compiler that property MUST be initialized"* - That's what constructors are for.

Comment: C# 11 introduces `required` properties btw. I'm not a fan though.

Comment: thx @Dai, exactly what I was looking for (and also op afaict). You should add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `get;` only properties with constructors is the way to go.

```
public class C
{
    public C(string a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public string A { get; }
}
```

> I would need to write quite of lot of extra code (i.e. the constructors).

Creating constructors nowadays is very easy. It takes:

- `Ctrl+.` + 1 mouse click in VS Code:

  [image]
- `Ctrl+.` + arrow down + enter in VS:

  [image]

---

## What does Microsoft say?

### 1. [Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types)

In [Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types) in *Non-nullable properties and initialization* shows 3 options:

#### a. Constructor

> Constructor binding is a useful technique to ensure that your non-nullable properties are initialized:

#### b. nullable backing field

> Unfortunately, in some scenarios constructor binding isn't an option; navigation properties, for example, cannot be initialized in this way.
> (...)
> One way to deal with these scenarios, is to have a non-nullable property with a nullable backing field:
> C#
>
> ```
> private Address? _shippingAddress;
>
> public Address ShippingAddress
> {
>     set => _shippingAddress = value;
>     get => _shippingAddress
>            ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Uninitialized property: " + > nameof(ShippingAddress));
> }
> ```

#### c. Forced initialisation to `null!`

As a terser alternative, it is possible to simply initialize the property to null with the help of the null-forgiving operator (!):

> C#
>
> ```
> public Product Product { get; set; } = null!;
> ```
>
> An actual null value will never be observed except as a result of a programming bug, e.g. accessing the navigation property without properly loading the related entity beforehand.

### 2. [Learn techniques to resolve nullable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-warnings)

In [Learn techniques to resolve nullable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-warnings) again there is no example for `get; init;` properties and the article suggests two options to deal with the warning:

- Constructor
- Initialising to `null!;`

  > to indicate that a member is initialized in other code.

### 3. [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

For more complex scenarios it may be worth looking at [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) and use some of the available attributes. I don't think this is a path for everyday code though.

Answer (score 0):

Make the properties have a private set function, and create a constructor in which you set those private property values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I could use [positional records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record):

```
public class Foo(string Bar, IImmutableSet<int> Baz);
```

I would get both the properties and the constructor in this one line.
But this only makes sense if I need value semantics.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 11 you can use the `required` keyword in combination with init-only properties, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties#init-only), (see also [What's new in C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#required-members)
).

For your specific example this would become

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public required string Bar { get; init; }
    public required IImmutableSet<int> Baz { get; init; }
}
```

This syntax is also previously suggested by @Dai in a comment to the original question. But this really deserves a proper answer!