# Intended or less-wrong pattern for using non-nullable types of class properties

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

There's a great question here about nullable types:

[Non-nullable property must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505347/non-nullable-property-must-contain-a-non-null-value-when-exiting-constructor-co)

Which has some great ways to overcome the warning, but I'm interested in the reasoning behind using any particular method.

I'm working with EF Core to craft an API. I'm being careful to never instantiate a model class without having the correct data, but the class doesn't know that so we get the typical "Non-nullable property must contain..." warning.

At least in my head, I *want* the null reference error to happen when appropriate, to be passed back to a client or to prevent inappropriately null/empty values being passed down.

**Example:** a "this field required situation", if it somehow gets past the front-end validation an exception should be thrown, and the exception handler returns an appropriate BadRequest response to the client. I'm currently doing this rather than handling each individual property with an explicit validation method, at least for required properties.

It's seems disingenuous to try to accommodate the possibility of a null being passed in by:

- Declaring the property nullable: this property really shouldn't be nullable, so I would just be allowing it in order to suppress the warning, which may cause functional issues or extraneous considerations elsewhere.
- Setting a null-forgiveness `null!`: which seems appropriate in some situations, but not anywhere where the property should be set and not-null at all times.
- Setting a default such as `string.Empty`: again appropriate in some situations, but not where the property should be set to something substantial and meaningful.
- Setting up a constructor: this seems a lot of extra work to do essentially the same thing, and I'm not certain this overcomes the warning as much as moves it.

1. Am I wrong in wanting to use an exception to catch when an instantiation doesn't set or sets null a non-nullable property? I only question this because of the warning about the non-nullable property.
2. Is there some other pattern I'm unaware of that would be more appropriate, and that's why the warning?
3. Am I just putting too much stock in the warning?

Comment: You could take a look at this: [https://github.com/cezarypiatek/CSharpExtensions](https://github.com/cezarypiatek/CSharpExtensions)
Specifically CSE001.
I think it's a decent solution to this problem.

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3630

Answer (score 1):

> Declaring the property nullable: this property really shouldn't be nullable...

*Shouldn't be* nullable ... or *cannot be*? The compiler can only tell about can be or cannot be null.

Declaring a type as non-nullable means that you really don't expect this value ever to be null. The compiler helps you to ensure that you never assign null to the field or forget to initalize it. That is the reason why the compiler expects you to initialize all non-nullable fields and properties to non-null values.

If you know for sure that the fields are initialized to non-null values you can declare them as non-nullable and use the null-forgiving operator: `private string _name = default!;` This can be useful when you know that the fields will definitely be initialized by an initializer method rather than the constructor before you use them.

If you want to throw an exception at runtime if the value is null you actually DO expect that it might be null in some cases. In that case you really should mark those fields as nullable. You then decide whether a null check is needed or when the warning can be suppressed with `!` or when an exception should be thrown.

There are also a [bunch of attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) that assist the compiler in its null-state analysis. This is an example of a property with a non-nullable type where the setter allows null anyway:

```
private string? _name;

[AllowNull]
public string Name
{
    get => _name ?? string.Empty;
    set => _name = value;
}
```

Here we tell the compiler that the out parameter is not null when the method returns true:

```
public bool TryGetValue(string key, [NotNullwhen(true)] out string? value) ...
```

This can also be useful in some scenarios:

```
private string? _name;

[MemberNotNull(namof(_name))]
private void NullGuard()
{
    if (_name is null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Name really shouldn't be null");
    }
    
    // _name must be known to be not null when returning from the method
}
```

The attribute tells the compiler that `_name` is not null when `NullGuard` returns:

```
NullGuard();
int length = _name.Length; // no warning because NullGuard has the MemberNotNull attribute
```

> 3. Am I just putting too much stock in the warning?

Probably yes. Don't forget that nullable reference types is just a tool which tries to help you not to run into unwanted NullReferenceExceptions. It also is a better way of expressing your intent.