# What is best way to create .NET6 class with many non-nullable properties?

Tags: c#, .net

I trying to create class with some number of non-nulable properties (>7).

If I do like this:

```
public class Meeting
{

    public Name Name { get; set; }
    public Person ResponsiblePerson { get; set; }
    public Description Description {get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Attendees { get; set; }


    public Meeting()
    {
        Attendees = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

I get warnings like this:
*"Non-nullable property '...' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable."*

There is a list of variants I thinked of:

- Default values removes this warning, but I think, that it will just add useless values, that in the future will be needed to be changed anyway.
- If I init all properties in constructor this warning gets away, but then constructor will have >7 params which is nightmare.
- I have seen that some people use "Builder" pattern to init classes with many params. But the builder itself can't prevent 'null' values (The builder will get same warnings).
- There is easy way to remove warning, by making *nullable* property in .csproj file from *true* to *false*, but I don't want to just remove that warning. I want to make class itself safe from null values.

Whats clean way create that class?

Comment: So, is the idea that whoever instantiates that class will initialise each and every one of those properties?

Comment: If the properties cannot be null then you either must initialise them with default non-null values, or require non-null values to be passed to the constructor and set the properties there. Anything else will allow the object to contain null properties after construction.

Comment: If you're certain that the person who instantiates that object will assign all of those properties, you can forcefully initialize them to null, with `{ get; set; } = null!;` (or wait for required properties in C# 11)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @canton7 Kinda yes, kinda no. At the initialization class can be half empty, but I need to be sure that before serialization (Or smth else) that every property will eventually have these values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-nullable property must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505347/non-nullable-property-must-contain-a-non-null-value-when-exiting-constructor-co)

Comment: @Yoro Currently, the only way to ensure that all properties are non-null when the object is instantiated is to use a constructor. `required` properties are coming in C# 11, which will improve this.

Comment: @canton7 can you give a link where I can read of future *required*? That's interesting.

Comment: @Yoro https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3630

Comment: *Whats clean way create that class?* - use a record?

Comment: @canton7 Looks cool. I found this with good examples https://exceptionnotfound.net/bite-size-csharp-11-required-properties/
That would be perfect solution.

Comment: [See here for Roslyn language feature status](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md) - The item you're looking for is "Required Members" in the table.

Comment: @CaiusJard If I understood correctly, editing a *record class* properties after init is impossible without creating new one. I need ability to edit.

Comment: records are immutable by default, but they don't have to be

Comment: Right, but if you have a mutable record, you can't make use of primary constructors, which means OP isn't gaining anything here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C#11 you can add a `Required` modifier.

```
public class Meeting
{
    public required Name Name { get; set; }
    public required Person ResponsiblePerson { get; set; }
    public required Description Description {get; set; }
    public required Category Category { get; set; }
    public required Type Type { get; set; }
    public required DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public required DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Attendees { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

This feature aims to improve how we initialize objects that do not rely on constructor parameters.

More detailed info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required

Comment: > Required members must be initialized, but they may be initialized to null.

So with `required` you can't escape someone setting a null value and get the same warning there as the property was meant to be non-nullable

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of non-nullable is to initialize class instances in a "valid" state.
If `Meeting` is part of a domain, having some logic inside, you can't initialize Meeting without initial values. I.e., `new Meeting()` doesn't make any sense.
On the other hand, if `Meeting` is a so-called data transfer object and it may be initialized partially, if not even empty, then setters are fine, and you don't need a constructor.

Comment: So as I understand the best practice is to configure "non-nullable" warnings to ignore DTO's directory?

Comment: No, it would beat the purpose. I wouldn't go for warning suppression. Instead of that you should explicitly declare property as nullable. See @GazTheDestroyer comment at your question.