# Why can't the C# compiler detect that this can't be null?

Tags: c#

The `Safe` extension method can never return null, but the compiler seemingly isn't able to detect that.  I think I read something about this being an intentional design decision for strings, but don't recall when or where.  Can anyone explain how to fix this (i.e., help the compiler along) or explain why it's intentionally this way?

```cs
Foo? foo = null;
Bar  bar = new();

// CS8601: Possible null reference assignment.
bar.NoNullsHere = foo?.Text().Safe();

// No error with the trailing exclamation point
bar.NoNullsHere = foo?.Text().Safe()!;

public static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static string Safe(this string? obj) => obj is null ? string.Empty : obj!;
}

public class Foo
{
    public string? Text() => "has a value, but could be null or empty";
}

public class Bar
{
    public string NoNullsHere { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Edit: the "right associative" answer provided by @sweeper is correct - the `Safe` method will not get invoked.  Given that, is it possible to do what I set out to accomplish?  I really prefer the syntax and intellisense support.  Also, my actual implementation accepts other arguments to the `Safe` method to optionally do things like surround the resulting string with some token (e.g., double quote).

```cs
bar.NoNullsHere = foo?.Text().Safe();
```

instead of either of these

```cs
bar.NoNullsHere = StringExtensionMethods.Safe(foo?.Text());
bar.NoNullsHere = foo?.Text() ?? string.Empty;
```

Edit 2: forgot to mention that @sweeper does provide a work around.  The required parentheses are a little annoying, but better than the alternatives.  Thanks all!

```cs
bar.NoNullsHere = (foo?.Text()).Safe();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69685202/6527049

Comment: @viveknuna That's a terrible suggestion. There is no error here, the system is working as intended. Why disable it?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel my intention is to just have a look, that’s it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?.` kind of makes everything go "right associative" (sorry I can't find a better word).

```
foo?.Text().Safe();
```

means "run `Text().Safe()` if `foo` is not null". So if `foo` *is* null, it will do nothing and evaluate to `null`. If it helps, think of it as:

```
// not valid syntax, but IMO a good mental image
foo?.(Text().Safe());
```

This behaviour is also why you are able to just use one `?` in a chain:

```
someNullableThing?.Property1.Property2.Property3
```

If `?.` were "left associative", `someNullableThing?.Property1` would have been nullable, and you would have to put `?` everywhere on the chain, even though `PropertyN`s are not nullable. Note that some languages like Kotlin actually implement it this way.

That said, I think what you meant was:

```
bar.NoNullsHere = (foo?.Text()).Safe();
```

This will run `foo.Safe()` even when `foo` is null.

Comment: Man, I should have debugged and tried to step into the code and would have been able to see what you've pointed out.  I originally accepted the answer provided by Vernou but changed to your answer.  I was very surprised to find that the `Safe` method doesn't even get called, despite the fact that it accepts `string?`.  TIL, huh?  :)

Answer (score 2):

You'r using the null propagation operator.

```cs
    bar.NoNullsHere = foo?.Text().Safe();

    // consider it will work like below
    if (foo != null)
    {
        bar.NoNullsHere = foo.Text().Safe();
    }else
    {
        bar.NoNullsHere = null;
    }
```

So the compiler is right `bar.NoNullsHere` can be null

Answer (score 1):

Sure, okay, `Safe()` can't return null. But that's not really your problem. Here's how you use it:

```
foo?.Text().Safe();
```

What if `foo`  is null? What then? What should be the result of that expression? It's going to be null, of course, because that's how the `?.` operator behaves. And that's why you get that error.

You will have to check that `foo` isn't null for it to work as you want.

Alternatively, you don't really need `Safe()`, you can just do that instead:

```
bar.NoNullsHere = foo?.Text() ?? string.Empty;
```

That handles both `foo` being null and `Text()` returning null, and coalesces that to an empty string.

Comment: Agree, I don't need `Safe` and could do as you indicated, but I prefer my approach (despite it not working as intended) syntactically and with intellisense editor support.  Is there a way to do what I set out to accomplish, or is it just not possible?

Comment: I added edits to the question with the work around of using parentheses to still allow the use of the `Safe` extension method.  I also explain why I want it - biggest reason is other arguments and functionality in that method that can't easily be replicated inline with null coalescing.